# Replace malfunction in userscript: adds current URL in front of result

Tags: javascript, replace, userscripts

I'm trying to remove unwanted parts in outgoing links on a website with a userscript by replacing them with nothing.

```
jQuery(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function(event) {
    jQuery(this).prop("href", jQuery(this).prop("href").replace(/https;\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/linkfilter\/\?u=/, ""));
});
```

Said parts (`https;//steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?u=`) get removed, but then not replaced with nothing but with the current URL.

Example:
I'm on this URL: `https;//store.steampowered.com/app/1091500/Cyberpunk_2077/`
There's a link ("Visit the website") to: `https;//steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?u=https;//www.cyberpunk.net`
The script should change it to: `https;//www.cyberpunk.net`
The script does change it to: `https;//store.steampowered.com/app/1091500/Cyberpunk_2077/https;//www.cyberpunk.net`

If I just run the function in the browser console, it works as intended.
Input: `"https;//steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?u=https;//www.cyberpunk.net".replace(/https;\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/linkfilter\/\?u=/, "");`
Output: `"https;//www.cyberpunk.net"`

Doesn't work with other replacements either.

```
jQuery(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function(event) {
    jQuery(this).prop("href", jQuery(this).prop("href").replace(/https;\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/linkfilter\/\?u=/, "TEST"));
});
```

Should be: `TESThttps;//www.cyberpunk.net`
Is: `https;//store.steampowered.com/app/1091500/Cyberpunk_2077/TESThttps;//www.cyberpunk.net`

Had to replace https: with https; because question was marked as "spam"...

Comment: You sure this isn't working? The semi-colons make it not work, because the browser is looking for a valid scheme and not seeing one, so it's assuming it's relative, but if it's a proper `https://` then it seems to work perfectly for me...

Comment: If you mess with this fiddle and swap out the colons for semicolons, then the behavior is consistent with what you're describing.

Comment: As said, only did the ; stuff because it wouldn't let me create the question with so many proper links in the post.

Comment: So when you put your code into a fiddle, does it fail in the same way?

Comment: Working fine there, but not on the real site.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6mf07pyd/ I can't get this to fail. These are the real examples of the content?

Comment: Yes: https://i.imgur.com/fX3j3gW.jpeg

Comment: That will not work because `TESThttps://` is not a valid scheme.

Comment: I also see, in going to that site, that the colon and slashes of the scheme in that section of the link are encoded. You'll need to decode those to get this to work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fw4tjvL7/ Try this one...

Comment: Doesn't work with my original script (without "TEST") either: https://i.imgur.com/U0LHVWG.jpg
Ah, it was the encoded characters... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because the resulting string does not start with a valid scheme, (i.e. `http://` or `https://`) so the browser is assuming that the link is relative and prepending the current url. It would appear that the colon and slashes of the scheme are actually encoded characters and need replaced as well. See the fiddle for handling that decoding and the resulting string should pass the scheme test and everything should work as expected.

[jsfiddle.net/fw4tjvL7](https://jsfiddle.net/fw4tjvL7)